# Changing the size of a Round Button in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

Is there a way by which I can increase the size of a Round Button in Cocoa? I am doing a Cocoa Application in which one of the view contains some of the user's avatars. I would like to use a Round Button and set the images to it. But I can't find any way to increase the size of the Round Button.

Is there some way of doing it?

Comment: you have to modify the frame property

Comment: @tkanzakic : Do i have to make a custom button?

Comment: no, you can modify the frame of any kind of button

Answer (score 1):

```
yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
```

//or

```
yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 60);
```

//or

```
yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 80);
```

Answer (score 1):

To resize the Rounded Rect `NSButton` you need to customize and you need to draw your own button.

To solve your problem use Gradient button resize what you want and `setImage:`an image should be rounded rect. then make borderless button

```
[button setBordered: NO];
```

now it will appear like rounded rect button.

To remove gray highlight use

```
[[button cell] setHighlightsBy:0];
```

Comment: I thought about that, but when clicking, it gets highlighted in the shape of the Gradient Button, which is a rectangle. I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: It is not working. It says "no known instance method for selector 'showsStatesBy:".

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 60)];
myButton.enabled = YES;
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

Change the 150 and 60 values to alter the shape of your button.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using images, they try with UIButton's method setBackgroundImage:forState:.

With this method, whenever you change the frame, it will adjust the image according to that.